# Python - subplot only displaying the bottom plot

Tags: python, subplot

I have an issue with Python plotting the data set as 'ax1' on the bottom subplot, and not plotting the 'ax2' data anywhere, leaving the top subplot blank.

Any help appreciated!

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
    fig.suptitle('Sea Surface pCO2 (ppmv)')
    ax1 = ax1.plot(interp_bathy.where(interp_bathy > 0).plot(cmap=cm.topo, vmin = -4000, vmax = 4000, add_colorbar=False),interp_pco2_pre.where(interp_bathy >-120).where(interp_bathy <0).plot(levels=np.arange(200,501,10), cmap=cm.thermal, cbar_kwargs = {'label':'Sea surface pCO2 (ppmv)'}))
    ax2 = ax2.plot(interp_bathy.where(interp_bathy > 0).plot(cmap=cm.topo, vmin = -4000, vmax = 4000, add_colorbar=False),interp_pco2_pd.where(interp_bathy >-120).where(interp_bathy <0).plot(levels=np.arange(200,501,10), cmap=cm.thermal, cbar_kwargs = {'label':'Sea surface pCO2 (ppmv)'}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to understand what [ax.plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) and [pandas.Series.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html) do. The way to do this would be to pass the axes to the `pandas.Series.plot` function. Instead, you are passing the plotted instance to `ax.plot` itself, which doesn't make sense.

Try doing the following:

```
data1.plot(otherparams.., ax=ax1)
data2.plot(otherparams.., ax=ax2)
```

In your case, it would probably be like:

```
dataset1 = interp_bathy.where(interp_bathy > 0)
dataset2 = interp_pco2_pre.where(interp_bathy > -120).where(interp_bathy < 0)
dataset3 = interp_pco2_pd.where(interp_bathy > -120).where(interp_bathy < 0)

dataset1.plot(cmap=cm.topo, vmin = -4000, vmax = 4000,
    add_colorbar=False, ax=ax1)
dataset2.plot(levels=np.arange(200,501,10), cmap=cm.thermal,
    cbar_kwargs = {'label':'Sea surface pCO2 (ppmv)'}, ax=ax1)
dataset1.plot(cmap=cm.topo, vmin = -4000, vmax = 4000,
    add_colorbar=False, ax=ax2)
dataset3.plot(levels=np.arange(200,501,10), cmap=cm.thermal,
    cbar_kwargs = {'label':'Sea surface pCO2 (ppmv)'}, ax=ax2)
```